# Spring security_Password Encryption

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Login using spring security is working fine for multiple users.
Now I've to login to the application using password, which should be encrypted in the database.

> **HomeController** : Here I'm retrieving username, password from FORM.
>
> **spring-security.xml** : Here I'm retrieving username, password from DB.

Now somewhere I've to compare these passwords for matching and then I've to make the person to login.

Please give me an Idea, how we can do this using spring security. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you don't do the credential matching yourself when using Spring Security. That's the responsibility of AuthenticationManager you have configured.

You can specify the encoder to use while matching credentials like:-

```
<!-- This is the authentication manager -->
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="yourUserService">
    <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

All you need to care is storing encoded password in your user details table.

Take a look at [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html)

**SPOILER**

If you are using Spring Security, you don't need to have a controller to collect user credentials. Spring Security filters takes care of that.

For example:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logoutSuccess*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/main.css" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" // this is where your custome login page lives.
                             login-processing-url="/loginProcess"  //this is where you POST your login form
                             default-target-url="/index.jsp" 
                             authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess.html" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider >
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

I suggest you to go through a reference docs and simple blog/tutorial (there are plenty).

Even more, give [Spring Boot Security](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) a shot.